# How to change the font size of Title in Navigationbar in Xamarin UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms

I would like to change the font size for title in navigationbar in Xamarin UWP.Also would like to get title in center of navigationbar. How can i achieve it. I am not able find a solution for it. Has anyone implemented it.

Comment: I tried but didn't got the solution

Comment: Can you post you some source code how you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Before customizing the page title font size please refer to the Xamarin.Forms  [`PageControlStyle`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/PageControlStyle.xaml#L23)

```
<uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
    <Border x:Name="TitleArea" Visibility="{TemplateBinding TitleVisibility}" Height="{ThemeResource TitleBarHeight}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding TitleBrush}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
    </Border>
</uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
```

As you can see, the title of `ContentPage` was rendered by TextBlock within uwp platform, and the style of TextBlock was `TitleTextBlockStyle`. So you could change the tile font size by modifying the [`TitleTextBlockStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources) within uwp client project.

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <Style
             x:Key="TitleTextBlockStyle"
             BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
             TargetType="TextBlock">
             <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiLight" />
             <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
             <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
         </Style>
     </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

But it does not recommend that change the layout of title. Because the internal `FormsPresenter` could not be modified in uwp client project when you custom `PageControl` style!

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft Hi, thank you for a quick reply. Now i am able to change the fold size, but still i have issue with alignment. It is not getting centered

Comment: Please add the `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` to `FormsCommandBar` property in PageControl` style.

Comment: I  tried it to put HorizontalAlignment="Center" to FormsCommandBar, but still it is not working. Moreover when i add the above style my page content is not getting displayed.

Comment: Please place the style of `uwp:PageControl` in `<Application.Resources>` with in uwp client project.

Comment: I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/FontSizeOfContentPage.git) to git hub. Please check.

Comment: I have deployed your solution and title is at the left side. It is not centered. Can you please check

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft I have deployed your solution and title is at the left side. It is not centered. Can you please check http://i.imgur.com/NVLuj3k.png

Comment: The screenshot above is mainpage of my application. And the title is in center of navigationbar. But I have not run it in mobile emulator.

Comment: Am i missing anything else

Comment: I have just tested on the real device. But the `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` has no effect in mobile device.

Comment: Does it mean that it won't work for mobile devices ?

Comment: No,I have solved the issue. Please add the `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` to  `TextBlock` in `PageControlStyle`. And I have edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: Its working now when it is a single page, but not working in main page as it is masterdetailpage, also have an issue now. when i add the second style, the content in the page is not visible. Please check http://imgur.com/a/JQ36Y  .Working for single page, but content is not displayed now http://imgur.com/a/TbZKF

Comment: Because I have deleted internal  `FormsPresenter` of  `PageControl` style for testing. This causes the page content to be blank.  And I have edited my answer. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: How can i achieve that, seems like you have deleted style.  Also could you please tell me why center alignment is not working for home page which has side menu

Comment: Because the style of home page which has side menu is [`MasterDetailControlStyle`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/MasterDetailControlStyle.xaml). It is similar to `PageControlStyle`.

Comment: Could you please post the updated style for getting content in page.  For issue in homepage i added style with `TargetType="uwp:MasterDetailControl"`, but i am getting error.  So does it mean that we should not center align data as it causes the page content as blank

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft Any solution for this?

Comment: You could change the  font size for title. But it is difficult to change layout of title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144516/discussion-between-renjith-and-nico-zhu-msft).